# How to join two mysql states different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Now i get the result about two querys but i want to join with two results

First query

```
select count(*) from ih;
```

This is result

```
count(*)
'200000'
```

Second query

```
select
GROUP_CONCAT(if(rating='01', cnt, NULL)) AS 'A',  
GROUP_CONCAT(if(rating='02', cnt, NULL)) AS 'B',
GROUP_CONCAT(if(rating='03', cnt, NULL)) AS 'C',
GROUP_CONCAT(if(rating='04', cnt, NULL)) AS 'D',
GROUP_CONCAT(if(rating='05', cnt, NULL)) AS 'E'
from
(
select rating, count(1) cnt from de.rec ri group by 
(rating)
) a;
```

This is result

```
  A, B, C, D, E
'1222', '2851', '4638', '4325', '29206'
```

But i want to get the result like this

```
count(*), A, B, C, D, E
'200000', '1222', '2851', '4638', '4325', '29206'
```

So if someone knows that the way please teach me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just put your select next to each other

```
select
(select count(*) from ih),
GROUP_CONCAT(if(rating='01', cnt, NULL)) AS 'A',  
GROUP_CONCAT(if(rating='02', cnt, NULL)) AS 'B',
GROUP_CONCAT(if(rating='03', cnt, NULL)) AS 'C',
GROUP_CONCAT(if(rating='04', cnt, NULL)) AS 'D',
GROUP_CONCAT(if(rating='05', cnt, NULL)) AS 'E'
from
(
select rating, count(1) cnt from de.rec ri group by 
(rating)
) a;
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `cross join`:

```
select max(ih.cnt),
       GROUP_CONCAT(if(rating='01', cnt, NULL)) AS A,  
       GROUP_CONCAT(if(rating='02', cnt, NULL)) AS B,
       GROUP_CONCAT(if(rating='03', cnt, NULL)) AS C,
       GROUP_CONCAT(if(rating='04', cnt, NULL)) AS D,
       GROUP_CONCAT(if(rating='05', cnt, NULL)) AS E
from (select rating, count(*) as cnt
      from de.rec ri
      group by rating
     ) ri cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from ih) ih;
```

I think your query can be simplified, though:

```
select max(ih.cnt),
       sum(rating = '01') as A,
       sum(rating = '02') as B,
       sum(rating = '03') as C,
       sum(rating = '04') as D,
       sum(rating = '05') as E
from de.rec ri cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from ih) ih;
```

Notes:

- Do not use single quotes for column aliases.  Use them for string and date constants.  Using them for identifiers is going to cause problems for you later on, when you have unexpected errors because an identifier looks like a string to the compiler.
- There is no need to do two concatenations.  One is sufficient.
- I recommend `CASE` expressions over `IF()`, because the former is standard SQL is available in all databases.
- The use of `GROUP_CONCAT()` here is quite misleading, because there is only one value.  All it does it convert the count to a string, which does not seem useful.

Comment: @hognkun . . . This does the same calculation as your query.  You should try it before passing judgement.

Comment: i already tried it but when i doing i got the result not needed data...